# Why is the content of tx different between monero-utils-deserialize and print_block?

Tags: monerod, monerod-commands, tx-extra, transaction-key, transaction-information

I built a private testnet with reference to https://github.com/moneroexamples/private-testnet.
When I used monero-utils-desirialize to check the public tx key, I noticed that the displayed tx content was different from the print_block command of monerod.

First, in monerod

> print_tx
>   f7356602a1b6e3efaf66d3ef96cc797384b03de8e8447c57457e52935da8c0b1
>   Found
>   in blockchain at height 760
>    print_block 760

Then the following tx information was output.

[image: print_block command in monerod]

Second, using the output of

> print_tx
>   f7356602a1b6e3efaf66d3ef96cc797384b03de8e8447c57457e52935da8c0b1 +hex

I executed monero-utils-deserialize. Then the following was output.

[image]

I found that the extra pub key was what I wanted. However, I was worried that the contents of tx were different between print_block and monero-utils-deserialize.

Why is there a difference between the two?

Answer (score 3):

A block is not a transaction. Obviously, if you print different things, you will get different results. This should not come as a surprise.

A block may contain more than one transaction (in addition to the coinbase transaction). It appears you are comparing the block's coinbase transaction to the transactiou you had the txid for. These things are also different, and will give you different results.